# How to merge 2 COUNT rows as a new row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to merge 2 rows as a new row in the `COUNT` result.

This is my current SQL code,

```
SELECT assignment_status, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM table_jobs
GROUP BY assignment_status
```

Here is the current result:

[image]

What I'd like it to be is

```
done: 8
started: 1
pending: 3 //*merged from to_fix and to_validate
todo: 2
```

Appreciate every help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *conditional aggregation*.

Untested without any consumable sample data, however something like this:

```
select Status, Count(*) as amount
from table_jobs
cross apply(
  values(Iif(assignment_status in ('to_fix', 'to_validate'), 'Pending', assignment_status))
)s(Status)
group by Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Stu's answer is probably the right one. Here are a few alternative ways to do it:

```
-- Write conditional expression directly in group by and select list
-- Downside, duplicates that big expression. Upside, succinct? maybe?
select
    Assignment_status = iif(assignment_status in ('to_fix', 'to_validate'), 'pending', assignment_status),
    amount = count(1)
from table_jobs
group by iif(assignment_status in ('to_fix', 'to_validate'), 'pending', assignment_status)

-- Write conditional expression as a subquery
-- Downside, less succint, upside, only writes the expression once
select
    assignment_status,
    amount = count(1)
from
(
    select
        Assignment_status = iif(assignment_status in ('to_fix', 'to_validate'), 'pending', assignment_status),
        *
    select table_jobs
) a
group by assignment_status
```